# Unable to use XML PATH with UNION ALL in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have used below code to generate Comma separate values, it was before perfect working without `UNION ALL` but once I apply `UNION ALL` with another SELECT then it is showing an XML like output. The query looks like:

```
SELECT ISNULL(STUFF((
SELECT plant from (
SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Plant as Plant
FROM ASP_MstSKUPlantMapping SKUPM 
WHERE SKUID = '702953' AND Plant LIKE 'P%'
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Plant as Plant
FROM ASP_MstSKUPlantMapping SKUPM 
WHERE SKUID = '702953' AND Plant LIKE 'S%'
) Temp

FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2,''),'')
```

Current Output:

```
lant>, PN05</plant><plant>, PN10</plant>
```

Expected Output:

```
PN05, PN10
```

EDIT: If I removed `as Plant` this alias name then it showing an error as:

```
No column name was specified for column 1 of 'Temp'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to use a UNION ALL for this.
It's from the same table, so it's just something for the WHERE clause to deal with.

```
SELECT 
 ISNULL(STUFF((
    SELECT CONCAT(', ', Plant)
    FROM ASP_MstSKUPlantMapping SKUPM
    WHERE SKUID = '702953' AND Plant LIKE '[PS]%'
    GROUP BY Plant
    ORDER BY Plant
    FOR XML PATH('')
 ), 1, 2, ''),'') AS [Plants];
```

Comment: That is what I was searching for to use multiple conditions for `LIKE` clause! Thnks

Comment: @PrashantPimpale try this instead of searching `and (Plant LIKE '[P]%' or Plant LIKE '[S]%')`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Sometimes people forget that `LIKE` doesn't only have `%` ;-)