# SQL like with two wildcards anywhere in text

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard, sql-like

Is there a way to create a where statement using like with two words (or more) but they are not in the same order as the words given?

```
select 
    i.ITEM_NUMBER as Item,
    min(i.ITEM_DESCRIPTION) as Description,
    i.ORGANIZATION_CODE as Org,
    max(m.MANUFACTURER_NAME) as Manufacturer,
    max(m.MANUFACTURERS_PARTNUMBER) as Partnumber
from mis.XXEAM_INVENTORY_REPORT_WITH_LOCATORS_CONSIGNED_MATERIAL_AND_CATEGORIES_TBL i
left outer join 
    mis.XXEAM_MANUFACTURING_PART_NUMBERS_TBL m on i.ITEM_NUMBER = m.ITEM_NUMBER
where 
    i.ITEM_DESCRIPTION like '%ALLEN BRADLEY%PLC%' 
group by i.ORGANIZATION_CODE, i.ITEM_NUMBER
```

I would like to search the description text above as the '%ALLEN BRADLEY%PLC%' or '%PLC%ALLEN BRADLEY%'. I would like to avoid using OR statements because the dataset is huge and the query can take a long time.

The wildcards can be more than two, I just took those two as an example. In my mind I would for instance prefer to fetch the dataset for the first word and then fetch from that dataset the second word. Perhaps the only way is to select into temp-table.

Comment: You say "the dataset is huge", but will the LEFT JOIN return a lots of rows or not?

Comment: BTW, where's the GROUP BY?

Comment: You can add two condition in Like clause [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51983151/7124761)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do two LIKE for 'ALLEN BRADLEY' and 'PLC'. It should work for what you want:

```
SELECT
    i.ITEM_NUMBER AS Item
   ,MIN(i.ITEM_DESCRIPTION) AS Description
   ,i.ORGANIZATION_CODE AS Org
   ,MAX(m.MANUFACTURER_NAME) AS Manufacturer
   ,MAX(m.MANUFACTURERS_PARTNUMBER) AS Partnumber
FROM mis.XXEAM_INVENTORY_REPORT_WITH_LOCATORS_CONSIGNED_MATERIAL_AND_CATEGORIES_TBL i
LEFT OUTER JOIN mis.XXEAM_MANUFACTURING_PART_NUMBERS_TBL m
    ON i.ITEM_NUMBER = m.ITEM_NUMBER
WHERE i.ITEM_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%ALLEN BRADLEY%' 
    and i.ITEM_DESCRIPTION LIKE '%PLC%' 
GROUP BY i.ORGANIZATION_CODE
        ,i.ITEM_NUMBER
```

Comment: Thank you! I was definately overthinking this. Sometimes when I look at code for a long time my brain freezes and I can't think outside the box. This is the correct answer, thanx again :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
PATINDEX ('((.*)[ALLEN BRADLEY](.*)[PLC](.*))|('(.*)[PLC](.*)[ALLEN BRADLEY](.*)'), 
i.ITEM_DESCRIPTION);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your need for a performatic, powerful query, it makes sense to create a full-text index on the column. It will benefit your query by using the index and also give you the flexibility when including new items to the condition. If the query is small, the LIKE will be enough, but for long tables where time is a problem, create a full-text index.

```
WHERE CONTAINS (i.ITEM_DESCRIPTION,"'ALLEN BRADLEY' OR 'PLC' OR 'any other item searched'");
```